# Rehash of a solution for cygwin/gfortran that does not work

Tags: linux, cygwin

I have Cygwin installed on my WIndows box.  I am trying to install a program that requires gfortran to build.  I found a few solutions mentioned previously such as apt-cyg gcc4-gfortran to install the fortran compiler.  When I do this, with a working internet connection, I get the error message 'unable to locate package gcc4-gfortran'. If I leave off the gcc4- part, I get the same error message.  While the previous solution worked 6 years ago for another user, it is not - apparently - working for me.  Can anyone suggest a solution for this repetitive problem?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### I am trying to install a program that requires gfortran to build

The latest Cygwin Fortran package is [gcc-fortran-7.3.0-3](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fgcc-fortran%2Fgcc-fortran-7.3.0-3&grep=fortran).

> gcc-fortran: GNU Compiler Collection (Fortran)
>
> ```
> 2018-06-26 17:34           0 usr/bin/f95 -> gfortran.exe
> 2018-06-26 17:43      934931 usr/bin/gfortran.exe
> 2018-06-26 17:43           0 usr/bin/x86_64-pc-cygwin-gfortran.exe -> usr/bin/gfortran.exe
> 2018-06-26 17:34           0 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/
> 2018-06-26 17:31        9702 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/ieee_arithmetic.mod
> 2018-06-26 17:31        2208 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/ieee_exceptions.mod
> 2018-06-26 17:31        1251 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/ieee_features.mod
> 2018-06-26 17:34       15411 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/omp_lib.f90
> 2018-06-26 17:34        5335 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/omp_lib.h
> 2018-06-26 17:34        2981 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/omp_lib.mod
> 2018-06-26 17:34         610 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/omp_lib_kinds.mod
> 2018-06-26 17:34       28053 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/openacc.f90
> 2018-06-26 17:34        3466 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/openacc.mod
> 2018-06-26 17:34         484 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/openacc_kinds.mod
> 2018-06-26 17:34       12388 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/finclude/openacc_lib.h
> 2018-06-26 18:58    20222483 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/f951.exe
> 2018-06-26 17:31      210238 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/libcaf_single.a
> 2018-06-26 17:31    13307770 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/libgfortran.a
> 2018-06-26 17:31     1050584 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/libgfortran.dll.a
> 2018-06-26 17:31         269 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/libgfortran.spec
> 2018-06-26 17:28      187195 usr/share/info/gfortran.info.gz
> 2018-06-26 17:28       22196 usr/share/man/man1/gfortran.1.gz
> ```

Source https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fgcc-fortran%2Fgcc-fortran-7.3.0-3&grep=fortran

This package can be installed using the [Cygwin install program](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe).